# AWS CodeDeploy - Error Code: UnknownError, Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen

Tags: .net, aws, deployment, ec2

Estoy realizando un deploy(CodeDeploy) sobre una instancia Windows(EC2) utilizando TeamCity, pero el deploy no se puede completar por el siguiente error:

> **Error** CodeUnknownError
>
> **Script Name**
>
> **Message** Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - C:\ProgramData/Amazon/CodeDeploy/427714e6-a149-4db8-a80e-sfsfdsdfsfd/d-PF43B220S/deployment-archive/Scripts\app\
>
> **Log Tail**

Por las pruebas que he hecho, veo que el problema son las carpeta anidadas, ya que, si elimino las carpetas que estan en un tercel nivel(Scripts\app\controllers) el deploy funciona corractamente.

¿Alguien sabe a que se debe esto?

Datos: 
TeamCity 
CodeDeploy
EC2
Proyecto .NET MVC

Answer (score 0):

Encontramos el probelma, se estaba haciendo el .zip con *PowerShell Compress-Archive*, despues CodeDeploy trata de hacer el Unzip con Ruby y por alguna razon no son compatibles.

la solución fue hacer el .zip en TeamCity con *PowerShell Compress-7Zip*, y con esto se solucinó el probelma y se hizo correctamente el Deploy.

https://github.com/thoemmi/7Zip4Powershell